# Image filtering by dividing the image grids with blockproc in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, filtering

I try to divide the image as same size grids and get the response of a filter over those grids. Each response matrix for each grid need to be obtained as separeate. For instance if I am filtering and image in size 500x500 with grid size 100x100 than I need to obtain 5*5 = 25 different response matrices in the size of 100x100. How could I do it at Matlab?

I 've tried blockproc but it does not give separate responses for each image grid instead it grids the image and run the filters on and gives even large response vector. Here is the code I used for blockproc

```
fun = @(x)  imfilter(x.data,filter,'conv');
img_res=blockproc(img,[100 100],fun,'UseParallel',1,'TrimBorder',1,'PadPartialBlocks',1);
```

Ho can I do what I proposed? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did

```
% step 1 divide into blocks
szM = size(image)
nb = szM ./ grid_size % number of blocks in each dimension
C = mat2cell(image,repmat(grid_size(1),1,nb(1)), repmat(grid_size(2),1,nb(2)))

% step 2: do something for each block (here MIN)
C2 = cellfun(@(x) min(x(:)), C, 'un', 0)
M2 = cell2mat(C2)
```